# data treatment using a data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am looking for help in a task. I have a data frame `df` with column name `col1` and values like below.

```
col1
   a
   b
   c
   d
   e
```

I need to convert this data frame as below.

```
col1
 'a'
 'b'
 'c'
 'd'
 'e'
```

Comment: Your column appears to be a factor. Do you want it converted to character or do you explicitly want to add quotes around it? What is the purpose of this down the line?

Answer (score 3):

also this will work:

```
df1$col1 <- paste0("'", df1$col1, "'")
```

or if you have to convert from factor:

```
df1$col1 <- paste0("'", as.character(df1$col1), "'")
```

... ok, that is not needed, because `paste0()` wants characters, i.e. factors are converted to characters :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sQuote`

```
df1$col1 <- sQuote(df1$col1)
df1$col1
```

Or

```
df1$col1 <- sprintf("'%s'", df1$col1)
```

Comment: That are two different results.

Comment: @jogo `sprintf` gives similar result to your `paste0` while `sQuote` gives a fancy single quote.  I don't know who is upvoting the comment.  Based on the edit in your post, though it gives some ideas.